# Appropriate values for `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax`, or `unit vector ratio={a b}` to get asymptote

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to graph a function that has `y=x` as an asymptote. In the following code, I have `$\sqrt{x^2 + x}$` plotted.  It does not look like `y=x` is an asymptote to it.  Are there values for `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax`, or `unit vector ratio={a b}` to get a visual manifestation of this?  Is there a more suitable function for this?  (I want such a function `f` to be continuous on at least the interval `$[0, \infty)$` and to be such that `$f(0) = 0$`.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=3.5in,width=3.5in, clip=false,
    xmin=-2,xmax=12,
    ymin=-2,ymax=11,
    restrict y to domain=-2:11,
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
    ]

\addplot[samples=501, domain=0:9.25, blue] {sqrt(x^2 + x)} node[anchor=south east, pos=0.95, font=\tiny]{$y = \sqrt{x^{2} + x}$};
\addplot[samples=2, domain=0:10,  dashed, -latex] {x} node[anchor=north west, pos=1, font=\tiny]{$y = x$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The asymptote of `y=sqrt(x^2+x)` is [`y=x+0.5`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=asymptote+of+sqrt(x%5E2%2Bx)), not `y=x`, so you won't be able to find axis settings to make it look like it was `y=x`. Why did you choose that function?

Comment: A suitable function might be [`y = x + sin(x)*1/(x+1)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=asymptote+of+x%2Bsin(x)*1%2F(x%2B1))

Comment: @Jake  I tried a variety of values for the `axis` options to get a plot for the given function that illustrates `y = x + 1/2` is an asymptote to it.  The graph of `y=sqrt{x^2+x}` is "close" to the line along the positive `x`-axis.

Comment: The wikipedia page on asymptotes uses `|x| + 1/x` for its illustration.

Comment: @Andrew Swann  I chose `$y=sqrt{x^2+x}$` because I wanted a function to intersect its asymptote.  (I carelessly supposed that `$y=x$` was the asymptote to it.)  Without adjustments to `xmin`, `xmax`, or `unit vector ratio`, I think that I need another function to illustrate this.  Any suggestions for a function with an oblique asymbptote - not involving the trigonometric functions?

Comment: Well, something like `(x^4 - 3*x^2 + 4*x)^(1/4)` has many of those properties.  However, I don't see this is a TeX/LaTeX question.  May be you should asking this on MathOverflow.